# Initializing structure variable members in class gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault

Yes, I know it's a duplicate of like a hundred questions, but I have been working on this for hours and nothing is working.

All I want to do is initialize some private variables inside a class definition.

The structure looks like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
typedef string DataType;

class Slist {
public:

private:
// private data type: Node

    struct Node {
        DataType    data;
        Node        *next;
    };

// state variables:

    Node *head, *tail, *cursor;

};
```

I am initializing them like so:

```
Slist::Slist (void) {
    cursor -> data = 'n';
    cursor -> next = new Node;
```

And this is giving me a segmentation fault. I know this means I am trying to access memory that doesn't exist, but despite these being private variables, I am trying to access them in the Slist CONSTRUCTOR, which would of course have access to them. If someone would tell me what is up I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: `cursor` is a pointer and I don't see any code that assigns it storage.

Comment: At first, write `cursor = new Node;` before using it.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't do that in the first place. Thank you so much seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not initialize or assign the pointer to a  memory location. Any pointer requires valid memory location to work with.

you can do

```
cursor = new Node;
```

Before using the arrow operator.